# Use of .RDA files in R CRAN package 'extRemes'

Tags: r

I am using the CRAN package `extRemes` in R.

By the command `extremes.gui()` the extremes toolkit opens. Now, the thing I want to do is opening one of .RDA data files that is included in the package, for example PORTw.rda. Now following the steps described in the tutorial (can be found [here](http://www.isse.ucar.edu/extremevalues/tutorial.pdf)) something goes wrong in reading the .RDA files.

I do the following:

1. In the toolkit go to 'File' and then click on 'Read Data'. Select the file 'PORTw.rda' in the folder 'data' under 'extRemes'.
2. Select in the follwing window under the heading File Type 'R source'. Keep the boxes Heading and Delimiter empty and save the file as PORTw.

When I press the OK button it gives the following error in R:

`Error in source("C:/Users/jawissie/Downloads/Documents/R/win-library/2.15/extRemes/data/PORTw.rda") : 
  C:/Users/jawissie/Downloads/Documents/R/win-library/2.15/extRemes/data/PORTw.rda:4:3: unexpected input
3: 
4: Ý9–`

Also when I try to open one of the .RDA files from the `extRemes` package it shows unreadable content.

Does anybody know if I am doing something wrong or if the delivered .RDA files are not correct?

(The .dat files of the same package doesn't give any problem)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.  The html version of the tutorial provides a link to the original .r files at; http://www.isse.ucar.edu/extremevalues/data/index.html .  Just follow the link to the PORTw.R file copy and past the URL into the Read Data dialogue box and the data will be read into the workspace as originally intended.

Answer (score 0):

RDA files need to be loaded with 'load'. When you "read data" you are using 'read.table'.